# Catching and avoiding memory corruption at fixed offset in physical memory

Tags: linux-kernel

We have a 4-byte memory corruption that always occurs at a fixed offset in the physical memory.
The physical frame number is 0x00a4d and the offset is ending with dc0.

Question 1) Based on this information, can we say the physical address of corruption is 0x00a4d * PAGE_SIZE (4096) + dc0 = 0x00A4DDC0. Programmatically, what is best way to confirm the physical address? Ours is ppc64 based system.

Question 2) What would be the best way to find out this memory corruption? The more I read the more I get lost with the plethora of options. Should I use KASAN, or CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC (debug_guardpage_minorder) option or a HW breakpoint?

Question 3) Since we know the corruption is at a fixed option, if we were to reserve/block that page, what again is the best option? The two I came across are memmap and [Reserved memory regions](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt)

Thanks

Comment: You only get to ask one question per question at Stack Overflow.   But to address one dubious premise of your question: you seem to thnk that "guarding" that memory against being used will help.  Likely it will not.  You need to find the _reason_ it is getting corrupted, and fix that.   For example, if you reserve that region, then the code that was erroneously writing to that address will trigger an exception, which will be just another problem to solve (admittedly tracking the exception might be a good start on solving the problem).

Comment: These are all related questions so I suppose they can be together. Isn't it?  Yes we are investigating the corruption. The guarding option is only as a temporary mechanism till we find the corruption (You know how it is a release always has to go to the customer 'yesterday'). If after guarding there is an exception then all the more better since we can identify the culprit. Thanks

Comment: Yeah - I take that back, I thought there was a one question per post guidelines somewhere, but it appears not :)   However, the [concensus](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post) appears to be that you should avoid more than one question per post.  One good reason is the question of "how will you accept an answer, if it only answers one of your three questions?"

Answer (score 1):

1.) You are right about physical address.

2.) HW breakpoint is the best if you have such possibility. Do you have the appropriate device (t32 or whatever) / debug port/ could it place HW break at physical address?

Here is the more generic and dumb case which needs no HW support:

If I remember right from your previous post, you suspect the kernel code as a corruption causer.
If you have read anything about KASAN, you probably mentioned that gcc part places hooks instead of kernel code loads and stores. The kernel part provides kasan_store_bla_bla_bla hook, which handles correctness of this store. Very likely, that default functionality wouldn't help you, but you can integrate your code in this kasan store hook, which would:

2.1)Take the virtual address passed to the store kasan hook

2.2)Finds appropriate physical address by page tables walking like this (the more convenient API exists but i don't remember the function name):

```
 pgd_t *pgd = pgd_offset(mm, addr);
 pud_t *pud = pud_offset(pgd, addr);
 pmd_t *pmd = pmd_offset(pud, addr);
 ...
```

As i remember from your previous post you get crash in userspace app, so you will be need to check all processes mms from task list.

2.3) Compare found physical address to the given, and check that written value is zero (as i remember from your previous post)

2.4) If match print backtraces for all cores and stop execution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is happening is somebody is corrupting physical address 0x00A4DDC0 and writes 0 to it. We detect the problem only when this coincides with text segment of some userspace application and it gets a SIGILL. Earlier we suspected DMA operation but now feel it could also be couple of our kernel modules. Our platform doesn't support HW breakpoint. :( What would really help is if we can log stack trace whenever this memory is modified. We will now try the perf option mentioned [here] (19725900/watch-a-variable-memory-address-change-in-linux-kernel-and-print-stack-trace)

Comment: We also tried reserving/protecting the memory using memmap. But from a different module we were able to write to it. I will go through KASAN in greater detail and get back. Thanks.

Comment: We used memmap to reserve 4K memory at physical address 0xA4D000 (memmap=4K$0xA4D000), still we hit the same problem (text segment corruption in an application) at PFN 0x00A4D. Any idea why this reservation would not work?

Comment: I have never used this one, so I can't say. Check proc cmdline - if this arg was really passed. Check syntax ...